# Apply design pattern to url with different parameters

Tags: design-patterns

I have a one type of url that their parameters might have different values.
Example:
www.mycompany.com/:location

```
if ($location === 'country') {
 //countries will be loaded from database
} else if ($location === ''province") {
//province will be loaded from database
} else if ($location === ''neighborhood") {
//neighborhood will be loaded from database
}
```

the url has more type of parameters that apply the same logic.

What design pattern I should apply to this logic?

Comment: Factory and/or chain of responsibility

Answer (score 0):

I would implement a `provider` which returns different `strategies` depending on the input parameter.

So implement a strategy pattern where the same strategy can be used more than once.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sign of Factory Pattern.

```
 public class LocationFactory {


  public Location getLocation(location){
  if(location== null){
     return null;
  }     
  if(location.equalsIgnoreCase("province")){
     return new Province();

  } else if(location.equalsIgnoreCase("country")){
     return new Country();

  } else if(location.equalsIgnoreCase("neighbourhood")){
     return new NeighborHood();
  }

  return null;
 }
}

public class Country implements Location{

  @Override
  public void load() {
    System.out.println("loading country from database");
  }
}
```

You can use it like this :

```
Location loc = LocationFactory.getLocation('country');
loc.load();
```

Refer to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm